# Calculate what day it will be 100 years

Tags: python, calendar-computations

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the day it will be in 100 years. I've written some python code that takes two inputs from the user, a year and day and then I'm trying to calculate what day of the week it will be in 100 years. I'm not supposed to use datetime but rather some logic that I am not grasping. Please advise how do I do this? Thank you.

Example output:

```
What is the year: 2022
What day is it: Wednesday
100 years from now will be a Monday
```

Python code:

```
days_of_the_week = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

year = int(input('What is the year: '))
current_day = input('What day is it: ')

# account for leap years
if ( ( (year // 100) + 1) * 100 ) % 400 == 0:
    days = 36524
else:
    days = 36525
    
print(days)
days_ahead = days % 7

print('days ahead (days % 7)', days_ahead)
# index of the current day in the days_of_the_week list
idx = days_of_the_week.index(current_day)
# print day of the week in the list where the index position is days_ahead - idx - 1
print(days_of_the_week[ days_ahead - idx - 1])
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_calendar

Comment: I have added the tag "calendar-computations" (yes, it exists!)

Comment: 100 years is either 36,524 or 36,525 days depending on where the date falls within the 400-year Gregorian leap-year cycle.  You've already accounted for this.

Comment: What exactly is the logic you are not grasping? Are you trying to implement an algorithm someone else told you? It might be more useful to show us exactly what they told you (in their own words) rather than show you code. If you want to debug the code, you can use the perpetual calendar to help you test it. After you've debugged it for a few selected dates, I suspect you may find that January-February 2000 and January-February 2300 have special behavior.